# Non-PC devices don't have access to the Internet

Tags: wireless-networking, lan

I have a home network and face an issue that all non-pc devices don't have an access to the internet, but the same time all my pcs (windows 10/11) have it stable.

Diagram of my net:

[image: Home network diagram]

Some times it happens that devices break through to the internet, but most time they simply don't have the access. The signal to the router/access point is stable and, for example, I can control the teapot if my phone connected to the local network, but I can't control it from the global one. The same with other devices. It doesn't depend on network frequency, the issue is on 2.4 GHz and on 5 GHz.

What could be a reason? What should I check/fix?

Comment: It is an incorrect assumption that the devices cannot access the Internet. It is the other way around: you cannot access your devices from the Internet, because they are behind a NAT on the router. This is likely how it should be. Otherwise, someone else might be able to control your Vacuum Cleaner, Teapot, Satisfyer Pro 2 etc. from the Internet, too. However, if you read the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) you would know this question does not belong here on Server Fault.

Comment: Why so complicated for a home network?  Perhaps simplify it and all will work.

Comment: @EsaJokinen, thanks for migration. I use official apps for vacuum cleaner and teapot, they give me access to the devices from the Internet. Of course there is some authorization.

Comment: @Jonh, thanks for the proposal. I described this all to explain the scale of the issue. OK, imagine I have only 1 router, 1 pc and 1 non-pc device (actually I tried this configuration), the issue is still present, non-pc device regularly loses internet connection

Comment: @EsaJokinen, [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bat4i.jpg) is a screenshot to be clear. And what about a smartphone? Why this doesn't have access (from browser, any app)?

Comment: I have an ISP Modem, a main (wired) Router and and Wireless router attached to the wired router. All ONE subnet. All devices (computers, phones, Arduino, Raspberry Pi) ALL connect, computers share files, ALL print.

Comment: @John, OK, good to know. Anyway this doesn't help me. I also don't have a problem to share files between windows-machines via SMB (and I can even access to SMB from android phone when it is in the network), if this is important

Comment: You say that sometimes you can access the devices through the internet, or is it never? Did you check the router's settings for any access limitations or firewall? Normally you would need port-forwarding and static IP addresses (or fixed by the router) to access devices from the internet.

Comment: @harrymc, yes, sometimes I can, but mostly no. For example vacuum cleaner finished its work 5 hours ago, but I've just received a notification about that, because it has just managed to send it to its server (internet access appeared)

Comment: Ah, so the above first comment is incorrect in that the device can be instigating the access to the internet. This is very different. Since the connection is by WiFi you should check for quality of signal (device too far) and for interference (device near to strong electrical fields or another router/switch).

Comment: @harrymc, I don't have a specific tool to check this, but my pc and smartphone are in the same place and first one has connection, another one doesn't

Comment: Your smartphone will have an app for signal quality/strength.

Comment: @harrymc, the signal is strong enough, but no internet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhVD0.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gOFI.jpg

Comment: If no explanation can be found, the problem is either with the router or the devices themselves (settings or firmware or hardware). The devices seem likelier.